# $L^2(a_1,b_1;H_0^1(a_2,b_2))\subset L^2(a_1,b_1;L^2(a_2,b_2))$ and Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.  Suppose $$u_n\rightharpoonup u\,\,\,\text{ weakly in } L^2(a_1,b_1;L^2(a_2,b_2))$$ and $$\{u_n\}\text{ is bounded in }L^2(a_1,b_1;H_0^1(a_2,b_2)).$$  Can we conclude $$u_n\rightharpoonup u\,\,\,\text{ weakly in } L^2(a_1,b_1;H_0^1(a_2,b_2))$$ and why?

**Notation:**

$\bullet\,\,\, L^p(\Omega;X)=\left\{u:x\in\Omega\to u(x)\in X\,\big|\,\displaystyle\int_\Omega\|u(x)\|^p_{X}\,dx<\infty\right\}$

$\bullet\,\,\, f_n\rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $E$ if $\langle \phi,f_n\rangle_{E',E}\to\langle\phi,f\rangle_{E',E}$ for all $\phi\in E'$, where $E'$ denotes the dual of Banach space $E$

Comment: Could you maybe add some remarks to your notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We have that $u_n \rightharpoonup w$ in $L^2(H^1_0)$ for some $w$ since $u_n$ is bounded uniformly in that space. Now to identify $w$ as $u$ simply pass to the limit in the integration by parts identity equation
$$(u_n, \partial_{x_i} \varphi)_{L^2(L^2)} = -(\partial_{x_i} u_n, \varphi)_{L^2(L^2)}$$
where $\varphi(x,t) = \psi(t) \phi(x)$ with $\psi \in C_c^\infty(a_1,b_1)$ and $\phi \in C_c^\infty(a_2,b_2)$, and then use the Reymond du-Bois lemma.